# Como puedo mostrar la cantidad de pedidos a través de una consulta en mysql "selec distinct" en PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

actualmente estoy tratando de mostrar la cantidad de pedidos de una consulta en mysql en PHP,  sin embargo no logro traer ese resulto a PHP mi código es este:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(distinct Pedido) FROM pedidos");


$qty= 0;


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {   
    $qty=$row['Pedido'];
}

echo $qty;
```

Alguien quien pueda ayudarme, por favor

Comment: No deshagas la edición por favor pues haces difícil leer tu código pues no lo tienes bien formateado

Comment: Disculpa es que marca error en la publicación, por eso lo edite

Answer (score 0):

Hacer uso de [**`mysqli_fetch_assoc`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) nos retorna el resultado de nuestra consulta en formato de array asociativo, es decir así:

```
"clave" => "valor"
```

Dado eso debes hacer los siguientes cambios

- Debes darle un alias al resultado que te retorna la función de agregación (*esa será la clave del array resultante misma que recuperaremos para acceder al valor deseado*)
- Cuando estés iterando dentro del ciclo accede al alias dado al cálculo del **`count`** en lugar del nombre de la columna

Quedando asi:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(distinct Pedido) AS miPedido FROM pedidos");

$qty= 0;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))  {   
    $qty=$row['miPedido'];
}

echo $qty;
```

Comment: Hola @Betam, ya entendí, muy buena explicación me ha ayudado bastante, muchas gracias amigo, Saludos.